# Custom environment variable to main assets folder

Tags: localization, config

I have a multilingual website which has a folder structure such as:

```
craft
assets
  js
  css
nl
fr
```

My goal is to link to the assets folder for my js en css files, but as I'm running a multilingual site I have set my config file to:

```
return array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

    'siteUrl' => array(
        'nl' => 'http://krycer.be/nl/',
        'fr' => 'http://krycer.be/fr/',
    ),
);
```

Which means that my {{ siteUrl }} is set to krycer.be/nl or krycer.be/fr
But my assets folder is one level higher.
I tried adding this code to the config.php:

```
'environmentVariables' => array(
    'baseUrl'  => 'http://krycer.be/',
),
```

and accessing it by using

```
{{ baseUrl }} or {{ craft.config.environmentVariables.baseUrl }}
```

But nothing seems to work. How can I create an abolute link to my assets folder?

Comment: I think I found a solution elsewhere. It seems you can define your own variables in the general.php file and get to them through Craft.config.variableName.

That solved it for me. Let me know if it's the right solution or if there are better ones!

Comment: `general.php` is the place to do this Tom.  What config file are you referring to in your question?  Most of the code you have there would be in your general.php file, no?

Comment: Idd, I was referring to the general.php file :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to just use root-relative resource URLs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript src="/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

The only disadvantage of that is it makes your site slightly less portable – you wouldn’t be able to run it from a subdirectory on a web server without updating all your URLs in the templates.

So a better option would be to define a custom config variable that holds the value of your site’s base URL in craft/config/general.php;

```
return array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

    'siteUrl' => array(
        'nl' => 'http://krycer.be/nl/',
        'fr' => 'http://krycer.be/fr/',
    ),

    'baseUrl' => 'http://krycer.be/',
),
```

And then access that config setting from your templates via [craft.config](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.config):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ craft.config.baseUrl }}assets/css/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript src="{{ craft.config.baseUrl }}assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Note that there’s no reason to place that custom config variable within the [environmentVariables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables) config setting. The top level of the config array will work just fine for this.

Comment: That solution did it for me indeed. The root-relative didn't work everywhere. For some reason it worked on images but not on javascript files. Very strange. 

And when adding custom URI's to my sections such as "customSegment/{slug}" it didn't work either as the root was relative to my index.php in my language subfolders.

But problem solved! Thanks.